# composed variable after Object Operator in PHP

Tags: php, variables

How can I build a composed variable while creating a variable in PHP?
(Sorry I'm not sure how to call the different elements)

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$language = 'name_'.$this->session->userdata('site_lang');

for ($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
    $data = $arraydata->$language_.$i; // problem is here
}
```

I would like `$language_.$i` to be equivalent to `name_english_1`, next loop `name_english_2`... The same way I built `$language`

Comment: don't generate dynamic variable names. that's just bad coding. use an array. `$arraydata->$language[$i]` is **FAR** easier to maintain/understand.

Comment: but the fields in my database are called ´name_english_1´, ´name_english_2´ so how could I retrieve them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an expression in a computed property, you have to put the expression in braces. Also, you need to put the underscore in quotes.

```
$data = $arraydata->{$language."_".$i};
```

However, I suggest you redesign your data structure. Instead of having separate `name_LANG_i` properties, make a single `name` property whose value is a multi-dimensional array.

```
$lang = $this->session->userdata('site_lang');

for ($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
    $data = $arraydata->name[$lang][$i];
    // do something with $data
}
```

Whenever you find yourself using variable variables or variable properties, it's almost always a sign that you should be using an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

First construct the field name and then use it for accessing the field value from the object `$arraydata`. So your code should be like this:

```
$language = 'name_'.$this->session->userdata('site_lang');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $var = "{$language}_{$i}";
    $data = $arraydata->$var;

    // echo $data;

}
```